# Jasper Report: List as Cross Tab column

Tags: list, jasper-reports, crosstab

Is there a way I could use a parameter of List as my crosstab column?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this in Ireport, You can do this in two way, either create a new cross tab report, while creating cross tab you can select parameter for rows and columns value, either edit the report and select that column where you want parameter value and there you can change the column by editing expression.

Comment: Can you site an example? I cant seem find a good example. I tried to print the list parameter and it returns [data1,data2,data3...]. I need those Strings as my column in cross tab. Thank you.